# Save Downloaded File in www Folder ionic 2

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic2

I'm creating an app where users need to work with large databases. Rather than having the users download the data and populate an SQLite database on the client (which would take a long time), I'm hoping I can use downloadable, pre-populated databases.

I found [cordova-sqlite-ext](https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext), which allows working with pre-populated databases, but SQLite files must be located in the `www` folder for this to work. Is it actually possible to download files to this folder in Ionic/Cordova (on non-rooted devices)?

Comment: do you mean www folder of project?

Comment: Yes. Cordova apps have a www folder, which is where the actual app is served from. When you build a Cordova app, the required HTML, JS and CSS ends up in www and subfolders.

Comment: You have no permission to write files into www directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good practise to store your files in app's directory. Check this comment of mine and see if it helps you:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues/881#issuecomment-270832521

I had a requirement of downloading a zip file(with sqlite file in it), unzip the file, store the file in app's directory and query the DB. I was able to achieve it using plugins and works quite well.

Comment: This certainly looks like it should work, if I switch away from sqlite-ext to sqlite. I'll give it a try and accept if it does indeed work!