# How to copy a .db file to-from 'www' folder with Cordova?(Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I'm using cordova-sqlite-ext to check and add information to a .db database, this works fine but now I must to copy pre-populated database (.db) to work with pre-populated information.

I saw that according to cordova-sqlite-ext its necessary to have the .db file in the "www" folder so I need 2 things:

1.- Copy a pre populated database .db to www folder to use it.

2.- Copy that edited database FROM www to any other location in the phone so I can send it through email or other stuff.

I saw the solution showed here:
[Save Downloaded File in www Folder ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42902610/save-downloaded-file-in-www-folder-ionic-2)

But this doesnt work with cordova-sqlite-ext

Thank you all.

Comment: Use this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-dbcopy

Comment: Thank you Joerg, I'll test it today

Comment: Joerg it worked! thanks, I made a mistake trying the "Copy" function instead "copyDbFromStorage" but I fixed. If you put your comment as answer I'll mark it as solution.  Regards.